# Why we shouldn't use == to compare strings?

Tags: java, string

We can create Strings using explicit or implicit constructions.

**Implicit construction example:**

```
String str1 = "hello";
String str2 = "hello";
str1==str2 // returns true, both str1 and str2 points to the same String object in string pool
```

**Explicit construction example**

```
String str3 = new String("hello");
String str4 = new String("hello")
str3==str4 // returns false because str3 and str4 points to different String object
```

Since it's preferred (memory save) to use implicit construction why we shouldn't use == operator? As far as I know the only one reason to not use == operator is that we can forget about not using explicit constructions and try to do something like

```
str1==str3
str3==str4 // and so forth
```

Comment: Try for example with  `String str2 = "hhello".substring(1);` and you'll see why you shouldn't use `==`.

Comment: Why do you think that every used string is a predefined one? What about strings from an user input? Or from a json object, or a file, or...?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Literal strings, coming from your code, are interned](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29). That's why they're the same object in your example.

But not all strings in your program come from your code, some come from various inputs (for example a user input, or a file) or from operations you do to build them, and those strings aren't interned (unless you ask for it). Those strings aren't usually `==` even when they're `equal`.