# Reverse Polish Calculator not returning the correct values

Tags: java, math, stack, try-catch

The following code is for a simple calculator that uses Reverse Polish Notation (3 4 + --> 7)

In theory, if the String "what" is set as "3 4 +" it should return 7. 
However when I run it it doesn't return anything.

Also if the String is set to "3 4" it returns 4, instead of an error.

If I have evaluate("3 4 +") the method will get stuck on the last catch block.

Any help is welcome!

Calculator is an interface:

```
public abstract interface Calculator {
    public abstract float evaluate(String what) 
        throws InvalidExpression, EmptyStack; 
}
```

This is the class I am having issues with:

```
public class RevPolishCalc implements Calculator {

/*
 * NumStack is a facade, basically an ArrayList
 */
    private NumStack values =  new NumStack();
    float answer;

    public float evaluate(String what) throws InvalidExpression, EmptyStack {
        if((what == null) || (what.equals(""))) {
            throw new InvalidExpression("String is either empty or null");
        }

        try {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(what);
            while(input.hasNext()) {
                if(input.hasNextFloat()) {
                    values.push(input.nextFloat());
                } else {
                    String next = input.next();

                    //Symbol is an enum {PLUS, MINUS, TIMES, DIVIDE, INVALID}
                    Symbol nextSymbol;

                    if(next == "+") {
                        nextSymbol = Symbol.PLUS;
                    } else if (next == "-") {
                        nextSymbol = Symbol.MINUS;
                    } else if (next == "*") {
                        nextSymbol = Symbol.TIMES;
                    } else if(next == "/") {
                        nextSymbol = Symbol.DIVIDE;
                    } else {
                        nextSymbol = Symbol.INVALID;
                    }

                    switch(nextSymbol) {
                        case PLUS:
                            values.push(values.pop() + values.pop());
                        case MINUS:
                            values.push(-values.pop() + values.pop());
                        case TIMES:
                            values.push(values.pop() * values.pop());
                        case DIVIDE:
                            values.push(values.pop() / values.pop());
                        case INVALID:
                            throw new InvalidExpression("Invalid Value");
                        default:
                            throw new InvalidExpression("Unknown Value");
                    }   
                }
            }

            input.close();
            answer = values.pop();

        } catch (InvalidExpression e) {
            throw new InvalidExpression("");
        }
        return answer;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of problems with your code:

#### Wrong way of comparing Strings:

In your code we can see that you use `==` to compare `String`, for example in:

```
if(next == "+") {
    nextSymbol = Symbol.PLUS;
} else if ...
```

You [shouldn't really do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29926514/why-we-shouldnt-use-to-compare-strings). Use `equals` instead:

```
if(next.equals("+")) {
    nextSymbol = Symbol.PLUS;
} else if ...
```

Or better - instead of a bunch of `if-else`s and `equals` calls, simply use a `switch` statement!

```
switch(next) {
    case "+":
        nextSymbol = Symbol.PLUS;
        break;
    case "-":
        nextSymbol = Symbol.MINUS;
        break;
    case "*":
        nextSymbol = Symbol.TIMES;
        break;
    case "/":
        nextSymbol = Symbol.DIVIDE;
        break;
    default:
        nextSymbol = Symbol.INVALID;
        break;
}
```

#### Wrong use of `switch` statement:

Let's take a look at your handling of the next `Symbol`:

```
switch(nextSymbol) {
    case PLUS:
        values.push(values.pop() + values.pop());
    case MINUS:
        values.push(-values.pop() + values.pop());
    case TIMES:
         values.push(values.pop() * values.pop());
    case DIVIDE:
         values.push(values.pop() / values.pop());
    case INVALID:
         throw new InvalidExpression("Invalid Value");
    default:
         throw new InvalidExpression("Unknown Value");
}
```

It **will not** work as expected, because you are lacking crucial `break` calls after each `case`. Simply add them like so:

```
switch(nextSymbol) {
    case PLUS:
        values.push(values.pop() + values.pop());
        break;
    case MINUS:
        values.push(-values.pop() + values.pop());
        break;
    case TIMES:
        values.push(values.pop() * values.pop());
        break;
    case DIVIDE:
        values.push(values.pop() / values.pop());
        break;
    case INVALID:
        throw new InvalidExpression("Invalid Value");
    default:
        throw new InvalidExpression("Unknown Value");
}
```

And your method will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

When you compare the string use

```
if(next.equals("+")) {
                    nextSymbol = Symbol.PLUS;
                } else if (next.equals("-")) {
                    nextSymbol = Symbol.MINUS;
                } else if (next.equals("*")) {
                    nextSymbol = Symbol.TIMES;
                } else if(next.equals("/")) {
                    nextSymbol = Symbol.DIVIDE;
                } else {
                    nextSymbol = Symbol.INVALID;
                }
```

Comment: or you could use a `switch` statement